# Spartacus icons for link components

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I need to show icons before the CMSLinkComponents, ex: in myaccount dropdown, we have list of link componet, before every link component i need to show icons. How can we do this. What's the way to do some changes in the drop down menu layout, whats the best approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace default LinkComponent by your own using the ConfigModule from spartacus at your app.module:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    LinkComponent: {
      component: YOUR_CUSTOM_LINK_COMPONENT
    }
  },
})
```

In your custom component template, you can add icons as desired.